# SQL: How to select a max value for each group per day?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

Let's say I have a table that has the following columns...

```
Name, Date, Number
```

And say we had the following data inserted into these columns...

```
Bob, 2011-11-22, 1
Bob, 2011-11-22, 5
Bob, 2011-11-22, 4
Bob, 2011-11-22, 3
Wendy, 2011-11-22, 3
Wendy, 2011-11-22, 4
Wendy, 2011-11-22, 2
Wendy, 2011-11-22, 1
Chris, 2011-11-22, 4
Chris, 2011-11-22, 1
Bob, 2011-11-21, 4
Bob, 2011-11-21, 3
Wendy, 2011-11-21, 2
Wendy, 2011-11-21, 4
Wendy, 2011-11-21, 1
Chris, 2011-11-21, 4
Chris, 2011-11-21, 1
```

Now what I'd like to do is get the max Number value for each Name, for each date. So my query result would look like this...

```
Bob, 2011-11-22, 5
Wendy, 2011-11-22, 4
Chris, 2011-11-22, 4
Bob, 2011-11-21, 4
Wendy, 2011-11-21, 4
Chris, 2011-11-21, 4
```

Any help would be appreciated. I'm using SQL 2005.

Comment: Yeah the actual query I'm working on has a lot more joins and columns, but I wanted to kinda dumb the question down the core of the problem.  The answers so far have definitely helped me get closer to what I am really trying to do. Thanks everyone!

Comment: Can you add a bit more detail of the final operation or query to aid future searches? It might help people to know in the future why the simple solution didn't work in a specific scenario.

Answer (score 24):

What about

```
SELECT [Name], [Date], MAX(Number)
FROM [yourTable]
GROUP BY [Name], [Date]
```

See:

- [GROUP BY (Aggregate) Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html)
- [MySQL GROUP BY - Aggregate Functions](http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqlgroupby.php)

Answer (score 9):

It's not as hard as you'd think.

```
select name, date, max(number) from table group by name, date
```

Answer (score 7):

```
SELECT Name, Date, MAX(Number)
    FROM YourTable
    GROUP BY Name, Date;
```

Answer (score 6):

```
SELECT Name, `Date`, MAX(Number)
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY Name, `Date`
```