# SQL GROUP BY AND MAX

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, max

I have the following table in my database:

```
-------------------------------------------
| value  | category |         date        |
-------------------------------------------
| 12.2   | A        | yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss | 
-------------------------------------------
| 13.3   | A        | yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss | 
-------------------------------------------
| 11.0   | B        | yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss | 
-------------------------------------------
| 11.2   | C        | yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss | 
-------------------------------------------
| 19.2   | C        | yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss | 
-------------------------------------------
| 10.4   | C        | yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss | 
-------------------------------------------
```

And i'm trying to get the Maximum Value(12.2, 13.3,..) and the date correspondant to this value of each Category(A, B, C).

Like this for example:

```
-------------------------------------------
| value  | category |         date        |
-------------------------------------------
| 13.3   | A        | yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss | 
-------------------------------------------
| 11.0   | B        | yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss | 
-------------------------------------------
| 19.2   | C        | yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss | 
-------------------------------------------
```

I have followed this link [SQL: How to select a max value for each group per day?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8230485/sql-how-to-select-a-max-value-for-each-group-per-day)

So I made this query:

```
SELECT MAX(value), category, date FROM myTable GROUP BY category;
```

But for some reason i don't know why it doesn't gave me what i'm looking for, it gave's me a wrong value of the **DATE** (DATE does not correspondant to the Max(value))!!!

Comment: WHat happens if you add your date column to your group by?

Comment: Yep, it's stored as datetime

Comment: Er, all the dates are the same!!?!? And it was your bad luck to follow one of the (relatively) few examples out there of how to do this wrong :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But for some reason i don't know why it doesn't gave me what i'm
>   looking for, it gave's me a wrong value

The reason it didn't give you the correct values in this case:

```
SELECT MAX(value), category, date FROM myTable GROUP BY category;
```

is that, when you include a columns in the `select` clause in mysql that are not included in the `group by` nor an aggregate function like `date`, mysql selects an arbitrary values for it, so that it gives you the wrong values not the values that corresponds to the max values.

---

> And i'm trying to get the Maximum Value(12.2, 13.3,..) and ***the date
>   correspondant to this value*** of each Category(A, B, C).

To get the `date`s that are correspondant to the `MAX(value)` try this instead:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM myTable AS t1
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT MAX(value) AS MaxV, category
  FROM myTable AS t1
  GROUP BY category
) AS t2 ON  t2.MaxV     = t1.value
        AND t1.Category = t2.category;
```

The join to the subquery will ensure that the returned date value correspondant to the `Max(value)` and will eliminate the other values.

- [**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0b104/2)

Comment: Thank you, i did not get exactly what's wrong, but your works fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using a sub qyery.

```
SELECT MAX(t.value), 
    t.category,
    (SELECT m.date FROM myTable as m 
     WHERE m.value = MAX(t.value) AND m.category = t.category) as Category
FROM myTable as t
GROUP BY category;
```