# MIN and MAX for certain rows

Tags: sql

I have a dataset (**myDataset.csv**) that looks like this

```
User      Value
Alice     2
Alice     4
Alice     3
Bob       9
Bob       7
Bob       8
```

... and so on for many other users/values

I would like to find the Min and Max values for each user, but I'm struggling with doing this through an SQL query(ies).

I broke down the problem and queried for all the rows for just one user (say, Alice) to get AliceDataset.csv and then ran this query to find her min and max value. So I know how to get the Min and Max.

```
SELECT MIN(AliceDataset.value), MAX(AliceDataset.value)
FROM AliceDataset
```

But how can I loop through **all** the users **in myDataset.csv** and for each of them find their min and max (potentially even using the code from this query presented above)

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL: How to select a max value for each group per day?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8230485/sql-how-to-select-a-max-value-for-each-group-per-day)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I'm using data.world which has a SQL query tool. I tried looking into which DBMS it uses just now, but I'm not too sure how I'd go looking for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `max()` and `min()` function, you have to use group by for getting each user max and min values

```
select User , max(Value) mx_val,min(Value) min_val
from your_table
group by  User
```

Answer (score 1):

Use group by and aggregation - this will give you user wise minimum and maximum

```
SELECT user, MIN(Value) as minval, MAX( Value) as maxval
FROM AliceDataset
group by user
```

Answer (score 1):

Aggregation functions are used mostly return single value. If you want to `select` any column with aggregate function you need to add group by clause with that column name which you want to add in `select` result.

So, in your situation you want to use aggregate function on `value` in your result and also want to show value functioned result with `User`, so you need to add clause group by with `User`.

So query will be:

```
select User,
       max(Value) as "Maximum Value",
       min(Value) as "Minimum Value"
from AliceDataset
group by User
```

Note:
If you want to add condition while using aggregate function, you need to use `having` rather than `where`.
For example:

```
select User,
       max(Value) as "Maximum Value",
       min(Value) as "Minimum Value"
from AliceDataset
group by User
having max(Value) > 3
```